# Meteor app loses connection to MongoDB due to large(ish?) traffic

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, meteor

I started learning meteor recently and I am developing an application that is similar to a bus timetable app; I have several screens (about 30 devices with browsers) and I connect them all to one localhost that runs my application on cmd (the app is offline using windows 10 with local MongoDB, no online server). Each set of screens display a relevant bus and its timetable, extracted from a MongoDB collection.

The app used to work just fine, but when I added 10 more screens, the clients seem to be disconnected from the server after a couple of minutes; I have meteor calls that display server time on screen, this time shows up as *undefined* when the server drops and I can't see any of my collections' documents via MeteorToys, I see the collections, but the documents are 0. Also, I can't log in to my admin page (which is a basic user interface that I made, simple MongoDB Accounts collection)

It's worth mentioning that the whole app does not crash; I can still navigate to my pages as my layout, HTML and CSS, still show up, just my server-related functionalities that stop.

I realize it's a traffic issue, as when I disconnect all of the screens and run the app, it works just fine. Also, when I reconnect one by one, it also seems to work fine.

I get no error on my console on the client, and on the server CMD, the application does not crash, it stays on with no error what's so ever.

Also, I added Meteor.status() ping to my console every second, and I get this

```
{status: "connected", connected: true, retryCount: 0}
```

which means technically the server is not offline?

I'm very lost, what can I do to rectify this?

**Update:**

I noticed that I had several ServerSessions that run on every second that get my time from the server. I changed them to normal Sessions and I'm now facing a different issue; I think there is a memory leak somewhere; when it freezes I noticed my RAM usage skyrocketed to 8GB (I have my max_old_space set to 8912 so it shouldn't be a problem) The normal usage was about when it runs is around 600-900MB

Then I get `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
=> Exited with code: 3`

and Server Unreachable on the browser with `503 (Service Unavailable)`
The server then restarts, and it does the same thing. Help :(

Comment: As suggested  in Victor's answer, how do you run your server? Do you properly build it for production?

Comment: For the time being, I only run it through CMD via "meteor" or "npm start"

Comment: Then you run your meteor app in development mode, which indeed does _much_ more computations than necessary and may increase your RAM usage overtime. You should [build](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html) your app for production usage.

Comment: I'm developing this as an offline solution; is there a way to deploy it locally? 
I appreciate your time, thank you!

Comment: "deploy" does not necessarily mean you have to publish it on public internet. Think of it as converting your Meteor project into a classic node app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same behavior with an app loading lots of data and doing computations. When the nodejs server CPU is on load, the app looses connexion to its node back end, and when the database server CPU is on load, the app looses connexion to the database.

Here are some advices:

- Start by this reading if you haven't : https://bulletproofmeteor.com/ It has been written some years ago but still a lot of good practices inside
- Monitor your app on your machine, try to understand what is the bottleneck: data transfers, disk reads, cpu intensive tasks ?
- Look into your publication/subscription model. You may send too much data to the client, maybe you can limit the amount of data needed ?
- if your setup is critical, don't run it on a single windows machine using the `meteor` command ! : start with building a proper nodejs app using `meteor build` https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html
- use nginx to handle incoming connexion, it is robust and scalable
- use a separate host for the database, and maybe a mongo replica set of 3 machines (this may solve your issue by giving more database availability, but I haven't tested yet)

*Edit regarding the build:* After building the app, you will obtain a folder. Here are the steps to launch the app in production mode:

```
cd into your meteor app folder
meteor build targetFolder --directory
cd targetFolder/bundle
(cd programs/server && npm install)
meteor node targetFolder/main.js #I use meteor node to ensure version compatibility
```

Comment: Thank you so much for these! Very useful notes.
I am positively sure you're right; I do have several computations (that run on a one-second increment with the server). I actually made some modifications, that original problem is gone, but now I think I'm facing a memory leak; I noticed that my RAM usage goes up to nearly 8GB and gives up (My NPM start is set to 8GB which is more than enough)

Then it times out with `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
=> Exited with code: 3` on the server consol, and `503` on browser